# is there equivalent of rsync in MS powershell?

Tags: cygwin, rsync, powershell

Rsync is very useful, I don't have to copy all files in a directory. It updates only the newer files.

I use it with cygwin but I think there are some inconsistencies, which are not the main focus of this question.

so is there an equivalent?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although not an exact equivalent, and not a Powershell feature, [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.10).aspx) can do some of the things rsync is used for.

See also https://serverfault.com/q/129098

Answer (score 5):

This works to synchronize directories between. Call the function "rsync  ". i had permissions problems with robocopy. This doesn't have those issues.

```powershell
function rsync ($source,$target) {

  $sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse
  $targetFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $target -Recurse

  if ($debug -eq $true) {
    Write-Output "Source=$source, Target=$target"
    Write-Output "sourcefiles = $sourceFiles TargetFiles = $targetFiles"
  }
  <#
  1=way sync, 2=2 way sync.
  #>
  $syncMode = 1

  if ($sourceFiles -eq $null -or $targetFiles -eq $null) {
    Write-Host "Empty Directory encountered. Skipping file Copy."
  } else
  {
    $diff = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $sourceFiles -DifferenceObject $targetFiles

    foreach ($f in $diff) {
      if ($f.SideIndicator -eq "<=") {
        $fullSourceObject = $f.InputObject.FullName
        $fullTargetObject = $f.InputObject.FullName.Replace($source,$target)

        Write-Host "Attempt to copy the following: " $fullSourceObject
        Copy-Item -Path $fullSourceObject -Destination $fullTargetObject
      }


      if ($f.SideIndicator -eq "=>" -and $syncMode -eq 2) {
        $fullSourceObject = $f.InputObject.FullName
        $fullTargetObject = $f.InputObject.FullName.Replace($target,$source)

        Write-Host "Attempt to copy the following: " $fullSourceObject
        Copy-Item -Path $fullSourceObject -Destination $fullTargetObject
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your script rsync.  I updating making a third option of purging files that are not in the source directory.

```
function rsync  {
param ( $source,
        $target 
      )

$WorkDir=Get-Location
Write-Output "PATH PWD:   $WorkDir"
Write-Host "SOURCE: $source"
Write-Host "TARGET: $target"

$sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse
$targetFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $target -Recurse

Write-Host "SOURCEFILES $sourceFiles"
Write-Host "TARGETFILES: $targetFiles"


if ($debug -eq $true) {
  Write-Output "Source=$source, Target=$target"
  Write-Output "sourcefiles = $sourceFiles TargetFiles = $targetFiles"
}
<#
1=1 way sync, 2=2 way sync, 3=1 way purging target files not equal with source files
#>
$syncMode = 3

#if ($sourceFiles -eq $null -or $targetFiles -eq $null) {
    if ($targetFiles -eq $null)
    {
        $targetFiles=""
    }

if ($sourceFiles -eq $null){
  Write-Host "Empty Directory encountered. Skipping file Copy."
} else
{
  $diff_command="Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $sourceFiles -DifferenceObject $targetFiles"
  Write-Host "diff command: $diff_command"

  $diff = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $sourceFiles -DifferenceObject $targetFiles
  Write-Host "---> Different Files from SOURCE to TARGET: $diff"

  #$diff_target = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $targetFiles  -DifferenceObject  $sourceFiles
  #Write-Host "---> Different Files from TARGET to SOURCE: $diff_target"

  foreach ($f in $diff) {
    Write-Host "--> Indicator: $f.SideIndicator "
    if ($f.SideIndicator -eq "<=") {
      $fullSourceObject = $f.InputObject.FullName
      $fullTargetObject = $f.InputObject.FullName.Replace($source,$target)

      Write-Host "Attempt to copy the following <= SourceTarget: " $fullSourceObject
      Copy-Item -Path $fullSourceObject -Destination $fullTargetObject
    }


    if ($f.SideIndicator -eq "=>" -and $syncMode -eq 2) {
      $fullSourceObject = $f.InputObject.FullName
      $fullTargetObject = $f.InputObject.FullName.Replace($target,$source)

      Write-Host "Attempt to copy the following => TargetSource: " $fullSourceObject
      Copy-Item -Path $fullSourceObject -Destination $fullTargetObject
    }

    if ($f.SideIndicator -eq "=>" -and $syncMode -eq 3 -and $targetFiles -ne "") {
        $fullSourceObject = $f.InputObject.FullName
        $fullTargetObject = $f.InputObject.FullName.Replace($target,$source)

        Write-Host "Removing files from Target that are not present in Source=> TargetSource: " $fullSourceObject
        Write-Host "FIles that are not in source: $fullSourceObject"
        Remove-Item  $fullSourceObject 
      }

  }
}
```

}

##Calling the function
rsync $SourcePathFull_Month_Day $DestinationPathFull_Month_Day